# Dynamically render partial templates using mustache

Tags: javascript, ruby, templates, partial-views

Is there a way to dynamically inject partial templates (and have it work the same way in both Ruby & Javascript)? Basically, I'm trying to render different types of objects in a list.

The best I can come up with is this:

```
<div class="items">
{{#items}}
<div class="item">
  {{#is_message}}
  {{> message}}
  {{/is_message}}

  {{#is_picture}}
  {{> picture}}
  {{/is_picture}}
</div>
{{/items}}
</div>
```

I'm not super-psyched about this approach.
Is there a better way?

Also note that the different types of models for the views can have non-similar fields. I suppose I could always go to the lowest common denominator and have the data hash contain the html, however I would rather use the mustache templates.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm thinking about calling `Mustache.render` inside one of the logic methods and returning the result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I started to do. Render a template and inject it into the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing you did, and for each property type i needed a dynamic partial, I just set a dynamic variable in the js data model that's being rendered in the template...

```
eval("this.set({is_" + this.get("propertyType") + ": true})")
```

or

```
this["is_" + propertyType] = true
```

At least I don't have to manually set the 'is_whatever' variable...

It would be cool if mustache.js or ICanHaz.js had some clever syntax for dynamic properties inside of mustache tags... maybe something like this:

```
{{>{{message}} }}
```